# Is there a British equivalent in architectural history to American cabins?

Tags: britain, architecture, north-america, great-britain

I've been watching a lot of American horror movies, and a big trope is the characters staying in old, abandoned cabins in the woods. Or if not cabins then lodges, or in Westerns or haberdasheries etc. Which makes sense, because America's such a vast landscape and such cabins were used by travellers covering hundreds of miles.

I noticed it's not a big thing in British horror cinema, and I'm wondering if it's because there's nothing like that in British architectural history (perhaps because Britain's so much smaller and therefor not needed), or if it's just not a very prominent trope in British cinema.

So, any architectural or cinema historians that could help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe the American trope is based on isolation.  The similar trope in UK is moors; because they are British, they tend to have [castles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyfall) rather than cabins, The other issue is that population density in the UK is (IIRC) _far_ higher than in the US; there are fewer remote habitations.   In the USA, an abandoned house is a symbol of failed hope. In the UK, uninhabitable land is largely marginal; isolation has connotations of marginal life, exile and outcast.  (opinion; I lack the scholarship to write a good answer)

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: [Montana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montana) is nearly twice the size of [Great Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain) (the island); but with a population density roughly 1/3 that of the Outer Hebrides. Think about that - perhaps it answers your question. To be clear: [Celtic Britain](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-population-size-in-Celtic-Britain?share=1) had a population density significantly greater than Montana has today.

Comment: Note how the bulk of the US has less than [10 people per square mile](https://www.vividmaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/US-density.jpg) while only one county in England has less than [10 people per square kilometer](https://i.redd.it/mp064srxfnu31.png).  (with 10 people per square kilometer being roughly 26 people per square mile.)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - Moors wouldn't have the plentiful wood available as building material that "backwoods" cabins in the US do.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: It's also fair to say that the population of Montana is far from evenly distributed:  leave out a few places like Billings & Missoula with ~100K people and it looks quite different.  Of course the same is true of Britain: there are places like the Ridgeway https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ridgeway & Great Glen https://www.scotlandsgreattrails.com/trail/great-glen-way/ when you can hike all day and see few people - at least off-season.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It is more likely that more people in Britain lived in cottages than in castles, whether in outlining areas or not.

Comment: It's not all about population density, of course.  Nevada and Nebraska each have pop densities of about 10 people per sq km, but Nevada is *much more* urbanized than Nebraska (and also much more urbanized than states like Iowa and Vermont, which have pop densities in the 20s per sq km).  Nevada just has a lot of empty desert increasing the denominator for pop density.

Comment: @Calum Syers  Wha tis the meaning of haberdaseries in "Or if not cabins then lodges, or in Westerns or haberdasheries etc."?  A haberdasher sells either men's clothing or small items.

Comment: @ MAGolding Ah, my only knowledge of haberdasheries was from the movie The Hateful 8, which was seemed to be more cabin like from my recollection of the movie (which I haven't seen since it was in theatres).

Answer (score 4):

While I can't speak to the horror movie genre, you will find occasional mention of such in British fiction: gamekeeper's cottages & crofter's huts, bothies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bothy and so on.  In real life, there are even a number of abandoned stately homes: https://www.loveproperty.com/galleries/64516/the-incredible-secrets-of-13-abandoned-stately-homes?page=1

Also, the trope of the abandoned cabin in the US may be more fiction than reality.  It's far more likely that any unoccupied "cabin" you might stumble across is really a vacation home.

Comment: Also maybe abandoned [crofter's huts](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/crofters+hut)?

Comment: @shoover: Thanks!  That's what I meant by "agricultural workers cottages", just had a brain stall on the right term.

Comment: Those are kinda what I imagined. I'm going to see if they've been featured in any films.

Answer (score 0):

There's Henry II and Thomas Becket's visit to a Saxon hut in *Becket* (1964).  It's not exactly a horror film, but it certainly would have been if the Saxon peasant family had been the protagonists....